# ant target to deploy war to tomcat7/webapps

Tags: java, ant, tomcat7, war, web-deployment

I want to deploy the just created `*.war` (exploded) to `${TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps` using `ant` target.

### CONFIGURATION

My tomcat version is 7.0.37 and `tomcat-users.xml` is :

```
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
   <role rolename="manager-gui"/>

  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager-gui"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1,manager-gui"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
```

`war.properties` is :

```
# War Build Properties

package.dir=${basedir}/package
war.exploded.dir=${deploy.dir}/war-ex
# --------- Tomcat Settings ---------------

# FIXME : tomcat.url=http://localhost:8080/manager/text
tomcat.url=http://localhost:8080/manager

tomcat.username=tomcat
tomcat.password=tomcat

context-path=/eccount
```

My `deploy-war` target is as follows (`tomcat-deploy.xml`):

```
<taskdef name="catalina-deploy"    classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask"       classpathref="catalina.lib.classpath"/>
  <target name="deploy-war" depends="build-wardir" description="Install web app">
    <catalina-deploy url="${tomcat.url}" 
            username="${tomcat.username}" 
            password="${tomcat.password}"
            path="${context-path}" 
            localwar="file://${war.exploded.dir}"/>
  </target>
```

### PROBLEM

When I hit `ant deploy-war` via command line , I get the following exception :

```
FileNotFoundException : http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=%2Feccount&war=file%3A%2F%2FC%3A%5Ceccount%2Fdeploy%2Fwar-ex
```

But, the same path `file:///C:/eccount/deploy/war-ex` is accesible via web browser.

### REFERENCES

[Deploy A New Application Remotely in Tomcat 7.0.37](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Remotely)

[Deployment of war file on Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/143267/432903)

[How Apache Ant deploys .war file to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6131462/432903)

[Catalina-Ant for Tomcat 7](http://paulgrenyer.blogspot.co.at/2011/11/catalina-ant-for-tomcat-7.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the issue is fixed :

### STEP 1 : update tomcat manager url for AT7

```
 tomcat.url=http://localhost:8080/manager/text
```

### STEP 2 : add extra role to user

```
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>

  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

Thanks to [Ant Tomcat 7 Reload FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10919612/432903)